# I write this program but i dont know what i am missing

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to the python programming so i am not getting what is my error about. so kindly help me to correct this code.

I tried to find out whats wrong but as a new programmer i am not getting

```py
class students:
  def __init(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello i am " + self.name)

p1 = students("Sumit", 28)
p1.myfunc()
```

It shouldn't give error but it showing error that objects cannot pass something like that. i am not sure what is wrong

Comment: As a general hint, if you get an error, copy-paste the whole exact error to your question, instead of "objects cannot pass something like that"

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor (`__init__`) should have two uderscores on each side:

```py
class students:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def myfunc(self):
        print("Hello i am " + self.name)

p1 = students("Sumit", 28)
p1.myfunc()
```

Many python 'internals' follow this practice of being surrounded by two underscores on each side. For example, you can access the variables in a certain class or namespace with the `__dict__` keyword.

```py
print(p1.__dict__) # Will print {'name': "Sumit", 'age': 28}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double underscores after the init function. It should be like below

```
class students:
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello i am " + self.name)

p1 = students("Sumit", 28)
p1.myfunc()
```

It's called the magic methods. Python provide this methods to use it as the operator overloading.